# Please configure the inventory detail for item

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, saved-searches, suitescript1.0

I am trying to create an item fulfillment for an item , the on hand quantity on item fulfillment record is showing as X for that item at that location , but when it says configure inventory details for line X i am not able to see available under the status column

I tried creating a saved search and getting the item's on hand greater than zero and location in the results but got as empty

I also checked previous item fulfillments for that item they are created successfully with on hand quantity but now i am getting error as - Please configure the inventory detail for item

Comment: Did someone turn on 'bins'?

Comment: that sounds that your Item is a Kit or you did enable BINS,  you´ll need to specify the details in the sublistSubrecord  var inventoryDetail = itemFulfillMent.getCurrentSublistSubrecord( 'item', 'inventorydetail' );  or in UI  theres a Box icon